# centos postgresql won't start now

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, postgis

I am not sure how to recover from this error...I am pretty sure I caused it via backing up data folder:

`/var/lib/pgsql/data`

to my own user space and then removing everything in that data folder and copying a diff data folder to it:

`/var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data`

So I did that copy and tried to bring up the server like:

`sudo systemctl start postgresql`

I got this error:

`Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

Thought oh no, removed the 9.5/data that was in /data and put back the original stuff tried it again and got the same error now (this was working just with what I thought was an old/wrong database hence me trying to copy the diff data folder) but now since its not working at all and i do open that postgresql.service file and get this:

The systemctl status postgresql.service call just gives me this:

```
[sthomas@sw-webserver ~]$  sudo systemctl status postgresql.service
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2016-12-23 15:31:03 MST; 53s ago
  Process: 9738 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 28078 (code=killed, signal=KILL)

Dec 23 15:31:03 sw-webserver postgresql-check-db-dir[9738]: Executing: /usr/bin/postgresql-check-db-dir /var/lib/pgsql/data
Dec 23 15:31:03 sw-webserver postgresql-check-db-dir[9738]: cat: /var/lib/pgsql/data/PG_VERSION: Permission denied
Dec 23 15:31:03 sw-webserver postgresql-check-db-dir[9738]: cat: /var/lib/pgsql/data/PG_VERSION: Permission denied
```

I am not sure at all what that is telling me or why it won't work.  Even when I backed out the hack of my copying what i thought was a newer database to the older space so that I could start the server with it pointing to the newer database.

Comment: Find out where your logs are .. guessing /var/log/postgresql* and check `error.log`

Comment: not there, I will keep hunting...

Comment: `sudo updatedb; locate postgresql | grep log`

Comment: Ahhh so no error logs that I saw it showed a postgres log folder of /var/lib/pgsql/9.5/data/pg_log/ and /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_log  which is nice, I cat those files and through what they said realized there are two data folders, and the 9.5 is the one I want, no idea why 
sudo systemctl start postgresql won't start anymore without the error logs...or how when it does start working get it ot use the 9.5/data folder.  Or let me start it manually, though this was progress. Thank you